# JointJS element containing HTML button onclick show form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jointjs

I am showing a form on `addDetail` buttton inside this element. How can I bind my data to this cell and send it to the server using the `toJSon()` method?

```
// Create a custom view for that element that displays an HTML div above it.
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

joint.shapes.html.ElementView = joint.dia.ElementView.extend({

    template: [
        '<div class="html-element">',
        '<button class="delete">x</button>',
        '<label></label>',
        '<span></span>', '<br/>',
        '<input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="name"/>',
        '<button class="addDetail">+</button>',
        '</div>'




    ].join(''),

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'updateBox');
        joint.dia.ElementView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        this.$box = $(_.template(this.template)());
        // Prevent paper from handling pointerdown.
        this.$box.find('input').on('mousedown click', function (evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
        });
        // This is an example of reacting on the input change and storing the input data in the cell model.
        this.$box.find('input').on('change', _.bind(function (evt) {
            alert($(evt.target).val());
            this.model.set('input', $(evt.target).val());
        }, this));


        this.$box.find('.delete').on('click', _.bind(this.model.remove, this.model));
        this.$box.find('.addDetail').on('click', _.bind(function (evt) {
             addActionDetail();


        })
        );


        // Update the box position whenever the underlying model changes.
        this.model.on('change', this.updateBox, this);

        // Remove the box when the model gets removed from the graph.
        this.model.on('remove', this.removeBox, this);

        this.updateBox();
    },
    render: function () {
        joint.dia.ElementView.prototype.render.apply(this, arguments);
        this.paper.$el.prepend(this.$box);
        this.updateBox();
        return this;
    },
    updateBox: function () {
        // Set the position and dimension of the box so that it covers the JointJS element.
        var bbox = this.model.getBBox();
        // Example of updating the HTML with a data stored in the cell model.

        this.$box.find('label').text(this.model.get('label'));
        this.$box.find('span').text(this.model.get('select'));
        this.$box.css({
            width: bbox.width,
            height: bbox.height,
            left: bbox.x,
            top: bbox.y,
            transform: 'rotate(' + (this.model.get('angle') || 0) + 'deg)'
        });
    },
    removeBox: function (evt) {
        this.$box.remove();
    }
});
```

}

Comment: how can i bind or send form data along with graph data

Comment: Inside the .addDetail.on('click', can you not post to the server the cell details which can you can get from  using                _.each(canvasGraph.getCells(), function(cell) {.....             })

Answer (score 1):

In order to save some data on your element you must follow this steps:

1. Add some `elementData` propery to the shape model.
2. Each time the user click on `addDetail` inside your element you must have the element id, extract the `elementData` out of it, and then to render the form (you can achieve this by adding custom event listener to your paper)
3. When clicking the submit form, add add some custom trigger event.
4. Listen to that triggered event on your graph and try look for the specific cell by the `ModelId` and update it.

### Here is the basic idea example:

1.your shape model:

```
joint.shapes.myShapes = joint.shapes.myShapes || {};

joint.shapes.myShapes.Element = joint.shapes.basic.Generic.extend({
    //basically the defaults function doesn't needed, because the set function adds that automatically.
    defaults: _.defaultsDeep({
        elementData: null,
    }, joint.shapes.basic.Generic.prototype.defaults),
    getElementData: function () {
        return this.get("elementData");
    },
    setElementData: function (elementData) {
        this.set("elementData", elementData);
    },
});
```

2.On your paper init, add your custom event listener function,
notice that you must have the ModelId to be remembered:

```
paper.on('addDetail:click', function (cell) {
    var elementData = cell.model.getElementData();
    elementData.ModelId = cell.model.id;

    formRender(elementData);
});
```

3.trigger some custom event on your submit and the object to be updated within the element model:

```
function formSubmit() {
    graph.trigger('custom:update', newElementData);
}
```

4.Add some custom event listener to your graph, add call the `setElementData` by the `ModelId`:

```
graph.on('custom:update', function (elementData) {
    var cell = graph.getCell(elementData.ModelId);
    cell.setElementData(elementData);
}, this);
```

Now you can send it to the server using the toJSon() method.